# How can I crop the image given to the model in Teachable Machines?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

So what I want is to crop the image before feeding it to the Teachable Machine Model. Because I trained the model with emphasis to recognize a small part of the image. So in the default code provided by Teachable Machine the whole image is given to the TM Model.

I have added the complete code down here.

```
<div>Teachable Machine Image Model</div>
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Start</button>
<div id="webcam-container"></div>
<div id="label-container"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // More API functions here:
    // https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image

    // the link to your model provided by Teachable Machine export panel
    const URL = ""

    let model, webcam, labelContainer, maxPredictions;

    // Load the image model and setup the webcam
    async function init() {
        const modelURL = URL + "model.json";
        const metadataURL = URL + "metadata.json";

        // load the model and metadata
        // Refer to tmImage.loadFromFiles() in the API to support files from a file picker
        // or files from your local hard drive
        // Note: the pose library adds "tmImage" object to your window (window.tmImage)
        model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);
        maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();

        // Convenience function to setup a webcam
        const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam
        webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(400, 400, flip); // width, height, flip
        await webcam.setup(); // request access to the webcam
        await webcam.play();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // append elements to the DOM
        document.getElementById("webcam-container").appendChild(webcam.canvas);
        labelContainer = document.getElementById("label-container");
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) { // and class labels
            labelContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        }
    }

    async function loop() {
        webcam.update(); // update the webcam frame
        await predict();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // run the webcam image through the image model
    async function predict() {
        // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
        const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
        for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
            const classPrediction =
                prediction[i].className + ": " + prediction[i].probability.toFixed(2);
            labelContainer.childNodes[i].innerHTML = classPrediction;
        }
    }
</script>
```

All i am insterested in is this line

```
const prediction = await model.predict(webcam.canvas);
```

Here webcam.canvas gives the model the entire webcam canvas as input to the model. But I want to crop the image before this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the line

```
webcam = new tmImage.Webcam(400, 400, flip); // width, height, flip
```

The first 400 is the width and the second 400 is the height of the webcam given to the model. Change that values to your wish.